# CSS make outer element fixed responsibility

Tags: css, responsive

I created 2 circle images-img

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-image">
    <img class="outer-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/190/008000" />
    <img class="outer-circle-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60/00F000" />
</div>
```

Added position relative to first element and absolute to the second so one stays over the other.

```
.outer-circle{
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }

.outer-circle-image{
   position:absolute;
   border-radius: 50%;
   left: 10%;
   top: 40%;
   transform: translateX(10%);
 }
```

1 cicle lays on the border on the bigger cicle.

Problem: If I play around with the viewport size, the small border cicle just floats around and I want to make it fixed on the bottom border of the big circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/u3mybo8j/

Answer (score 0):

The `position: relative;` should be given to your parent class, which is `circle-image`. Please find the code snippet below

```css
.circle-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.outer-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.outer-circle-image {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  bottom: calc(50% - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle-image">
    <img class="outer-circle" src="https://via.placeholder.com/190/008000" />
    <img class="outer-circle-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/60/00F000" />
  </div>
</div>
```